# Unable to raise div with ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, clientscript

Actually, I'm trying to show a `div` on a condition by using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`.

But, I'm unable to show that. My code goes like this :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "<script> $('#PopupMessgebox').modal('toggle');</script>");
```

`PopupMessgebox` is the `div` id

Actually, its a `Login` form and the `login click` is designed using `list li` and for the first time, on clicking that the popup (div) is showing and it is working fine. But, if there is any authentication problem, we are trying to show an error in the `div` and that `div` should be `popped out`. But that doesn't work :(

My `div` code :

```
 <div id="PopupMessgebox" class="deleteModal modal hide">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert-delete">
                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lbl_Msg" runat="server" Text="Hi" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <button class="button grey-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the javascript in the document on ready

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "<script> $(document).ready(function() {$('#PopupMessgebox').modal('toggle');}</script>");
```

Comment: I am thinking it is a problem with the html of your PopupMessgebox, can you post the html for it?

Comment: I just used your HTML and the C# code and I was able to get this to work.  When exactly are you calling the startup script?

Comment: I'm using this exactly when a login fails

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#PopupMessgebox').modal('toggle');</script>");
```

Comment: that doesn't help even :(

Comment: @RealSteel - Are you sure it inserts the startup script, you can check by having a simple alert box and test it.

Comment: yeah...alerts are working there..
this code works

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Email Address does not exist');", true);